# Gson is not ignoring said @Expose annotations

Tags: java, gson

Code:

```java
    public class Crate {

    private final MapPosition cratePosition;
    private final int tierId;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private final Inventory inventory;

    public Crate(MapPosition cratePosition, int tierId) {
        this.cratePosition = cratePosition;
        this.tierId = tierId;
        this.inventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9*3, "Supply Crate");
    }

    public void replenishCrates(CrateConfig config) {
        List<CrateContent> contents = config.getContentByTier(tierId);
        //TODO: 
    }


    public Inventory getInventory() {
         return inventory;
    }

    public Location toLocation(World world) {
        return cratePosition.toLocation(world);
    }

    public MapPosition getCratePosition() {
        return cratePosition;
    }

    public int getTierId() {
        return tierId;
    }}
```

The `@Expose` is being ignored and returning a null pointer exception when trying to deserialize and serialize the class contents. I have made sure to also include the correct GsonBuilder modifications, as stated in Gson's documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is not because `@Expose` is being ignored but rather because `@Expose` **is missing on the other attributes**.

The GsonBuilder's modification you are refering to is the following:

> This annotation has no effect unless you build Gson with a GsonBuilder and invoke `GsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` method.

But thank God the authors have correctly named the method and it will do just what it is expressing: **it will exclude every field that is not marked with the @Expose annotation**.

Here is an illustration based on your code (a little bit different because you did not share a completely reproductible sample)

```
public class Crate {

    private final String cratePosition;

    private final int tierId;

    @Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)
    private final Inventory inventory;

    public Crate(String cratePosition, int tierId) {
        this.cratePosition = cratePosition;
        this.tierId = tierId;
        this.inventory = new Inventory("IV-ID-111000", 10200);
    }

    public Inventory getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    public int getTierId() {
        return tierId;
    }

    public String getCratePosition() {
        return cratePosition;
    }
}
```

And the following test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
        Crate crate = new Crate("484:125.52", 1250);
        String jsonString = gson.toJson(crate);

        System.out.println(jsonString);

        String json = "{\"cratePosition\":\"4894:125.52\",\"tierId\":2350}";
        Crate deserialized = gson.fromJson(json, Crate.class);

        System.out.println(deserialized.getCratePosition() + ":" + deserialized.getTierId());
    }
```

In the current case I have no @Expose annotation on `cratePosition` and `tierId` fields, **so they are excluded from the serialization and deserialization**. Therefore my test returns:

{}

null:0

Now let's add the @Expose annotation on the `cratePosition` and `tierId` fields in the Crate class:

```
 @Expose()
 private final String cratePosition;

 @Expose()
 private final int tierId;
```

By default the serialize and deserialize parameters of the @Expose annotation are both set to true. You can play with it and change the values to see the differences it produces.

If I run the test again I have:

{"cratePosition":"484:125.52","tierId":1250}

4894:125.52:2350

Comment: Pity there isn’t a simple way to exclude just the fields you don’t want and continue to include all the rest by default. By turning on `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()` you then have to explicitly mark all fields that you want to include in the json, which is a lot of work.